# Simple spring boot application not works

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have created very simple spring boot application. But it dose not return the expected output. I have mentioned tried code below.

Main:

```
package com.example.practice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
package com.example.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ControllerClass {
    
    
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public String getAllUsers() {
        return "get All users";
    }

}
```

Properties:

```
server.port=8090
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.practice</groupId>
    <artifactId>practice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Practice project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried in my browser by using this endpoint: `http://localhost:8090/api/all`

expected output:

`get All users`

current output:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Nov 01 00:44:41 IST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

What is the wrong I have done in my code. I am new to `spring boot`. Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: what is the package name for those classes ?

Comment: @SKumar I updated question with packages

Comment: Add your controllers in child package of `com.example.practice`. So better use something like `com.example.practice.controller` instead of `com.example.controller` .

Comment: When you run a Spring Boot Application, (i.e. a class annotated with @SpringBootApplication), Spring will only scan the classes below your main class package. Make sure that your main class is in a root package above other classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be the problem with packages of classes.

Make sure your `ControllerClass` is in the subpackage of `DemoApplication` (for example, `DemoApplication` is in `org.example` package and controller is in `org.example.controllers` package) or use `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "package.with.your.controller")`

The problem is, the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation consists of:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
```

`@ComponentScan` here is without arguments, so according to docs, scanning will occur from the package of the class that declares this annotation. It will scan `com.example.practice` and subpackages, but not `com.example.controllers`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ControllerClass {
    
    
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getAllUsers() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("get All users",HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Upd. It looks that you have also different packages

```
package com.example.practice;
package com.example.controller;
```

and @SpringBootApplication can't autoscan your beans. There are two ways to resolve it:

1. Move DemoApplication class to next path com.example this necessary for spring boot to autoscan beans in packages below.
2. You need to add additional annotation @ComponentScan(“com.example”) to your DemoApplication

Comment: It is not necessary to return `ResponseEntity`. Your answer doesn’t explain what you think is wrong with OP’s code, just suggest a magic potion.

Comment: Yes, @AbhijitSarkar you right, thanks. I don't catch that there are different packages.